# Not able to balance a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I am new to algorithms and I am learning binary trees and how to balance them. The problem I am facing is that even after balancing the binary tree I get the height of the tree same as it was before. In my opinion after balancing (which has room for balancing)  a binary tree the height of the tree changes. Following is my code: -

```
class Node
{
   Node left;
   Node right;
   int info;
   public Node(int info)
   {
      this.info = info;
   }
}
public class NewBST
{
   public Node root;

   public NewBST()
   { }
   // ADD
   public boolean add(int info){
      if( root == null )
      {
         root = new Node(info);
         return true;
      }
      else
         return addRec(info, root);
   }
   public boolean addRec(int info, Node n)
   {
      if( info <= n.info )
      {
         if( n.left == null )
         {
            n.left = new Node(info);
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return addRec(info, n.left);
         }
      }
      if( info > n.info )
      {
         if( n.right == null )
         {
            n.right = new Node(info);
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return addRec(info, n.right);
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   // CONTAINS
   public boolean contains( int v )
   {
      return contains(v, root);
   }
   public boolean contains( int v, Node n )
   {
      if(n== null){
        return false;
      }
      else if(v == n.info){
        return true;
      }
      else if(v <n.info){
        return contains(v,n.left);
      }
      else{
        return contains(v, n.right);
      }
      //return true;
    }
// MIN
   public int min(Node n)
   {
      if( n.left != null )
         return min(n.left);
      return n.info;
   }

  //HEIGHT
   public int height(Node n)
   {
      //fix this code!
      if(n==null){
        return 0;
      }
      return 1+ Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right));
   }
   public int height()
   {
      return height(root);
   }

   // DISPLAY
   public void display( int n ){
      if( n == 0 )
      {
         infix( root );
         System.out.println();
      }
      else if( n == 1 )
      {
         postfix( root );
         System.out.println();
      }
      else if( n == 2 )
      {
         prefix( root );
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
   // TRAVERSE
   public void prefix(Node n)
   {
    if(n!=null)
        System.out.print(n.info +" ");
        prefix(n.left);
        prefix(n.right);
   }

   public void postfix(Node n)
   {
    if(n!=null){
        postfix(n.left);
        postfix(n.right);
        System.out.print(n.info + " ");
    }
   }

    public void infix(Node n)
   {
    if(n!=null){
        infix(n.left);
        System.out.print(n.info + " ");
            infix(n.right);
    }
   }


   public void infix(Node n, ArrayList<Integer> list)
   {
    if(n!=null){
        infix(n.left,list);
        list.add(n.info);
        infix(n.right,list);
    }
   }
//BALANCE
   public void balance()
   {
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    NewBST bst= new NewBST();
    infix(root, list);

    balRec(list, 0, list.size()-1,bst);

   }

   public void balRec(ArrayList<Integer> list, int low, int high,NewBST bst){
      if( high<low){
         return;
      }
    int mid= (low + high)/2;
    bst.add(list.get(mid));
    balRec(list, low, mid-1,bst);
    balRec(list,mid+1, high,bst);
   }

  //MAIN
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList<Integer> store = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      NewBST bst = new NewBST();
      int nCount = 0;
      while( nCount < 32 )
      {
         int t = (int)(Math.random() * 36);
         if( !bst.contains(t) )
         {
            bst.add(t);
            store.add(t);
            nCount++;
         }
      }
      System.out.print( "Height of tree = " + bst.height());
      bst.balance();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println( "Height of tree = " + bst.height());
      bst.display(0);

   }
}
```

I am not sure if the code is even balancing my binary tree correctly. I have spent hours debugging this and have not been able to come up with a fix/solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me explain a height-scheme for balancing a binary search tree that. Height balanced binary tree is defined as a binary tree in which the difference between height of the two sub-trees (left and right) is never more than one.

Your problem is that you are getting the same height even after balancing the tree.  I see a small mistake in your code.  After balancing you have to assign the new value to the root node. This is necessary to calculate height of balanced binary tree. So, add following to your balance method code:

```
public void balance(){
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    NewBST bst= new NewBST();
    infix(root, list);

    balRec(list, 0, list.size()-1,bst);
    root= bst.root;     
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The solution worked. A minor mistake that I was not able to find while I was debugging.

Comment: Great !! another suggestion add loggers to your code that will help you in knowing the control flow of the program.